# How does Indonesia's development and test vehicle work? Could something like this reach space or even orbit when scaled up?

Tags: launch, identify-this-object

Phys.org's [Blast off: space minnow Indonesia eyes celestial success](https://phys.org/news/2020-03-blast-space-minnow-indonesia-eyes.html) says

> It's a very long way from a Mission Control in Houston, but the Southeast Asian archipelago's answer to NASA has big hopes and is now planning to build its first spaceport on a tropical island off the coast of easternmost Papua.
>
> "We've got a dream to put our own satellite-launching rocket 200 or 300 kilometres into space within five years," said Lilis Mariani, head of the Rocket Technology Centre at the National Institute of Aeronautics and Space, known as Lapan.

and later

> "It was stable on take off and moved well," said Sri Kilawati, head of the Centre's rocket control programme.
>
> **"The objective was to study rocket control. They travel at a very high rate of speed so you've got to observe their behaviour," she added.**

So I believe that vehicle shown is primarily for testing subsystems like control.

But I'm curious why it looks like this. There's what looks like a solid booster canted from the bottom that drops off, and an air scoop on top, and a nozzle in the back.

**Question:** What is this? How does it work? Could something like this reach space or even orbit when scaled up?

[image: Blast off: space minnow Indonesia eyes celestial success]

[image: Blast off: space minnow Indonesia eyes celestial success]

[image: Blast off: space minnow Indonesia eyes celestial success]

Comment: Wow, that is easily the best (visual) design I've ever seen for a scientific instrument. It's downright as beautiful as a McLaren. Gotta love the GoPro on top of it too!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn other GoPro's in spaaaaaace!  [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19440/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20786/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30911/12102)

Comment: [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31438/12102), [5](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30902/12102)

Comment: I note that the article now says “...sounding rocket into space within 5 years” (i.e. suborbital) rather than “satellite-launching rocket” (i.e. orbital) as quoted here.

Comment: I note also that the article refers to *Indonesia’s space agency* as “a relative minnow” (with its US$45 million annual budget) — the vehicle is not named “space minnow” as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I see what you mean. I've hacked out an adjusted title, if you can think of a better way to write it please feel free to edit/improve. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad, I could already see the sitcom https://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/screenshot-50.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the intake and rear nozzle, this *looks* like a rocket-boosted air-breathing cruise missile -- Organic Marble notes that it's not unlike a scaled-down [SM-62 Snark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM-62_Snark). In this particular flight (of “a few hundred meters”) [only rocket powered and glide portions of flight are happening (YouTube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaoZ5uTDVQ8); I assume that if the design includes a jet engine of some kind, it wasn’t tested on this launch.

I had a brief thought that the intake could be for a ram air turbine to power the control hardware, but it’s rather large for that, and doesn’t explain the nozzle at the back.

So my guess is that this hardware design will in future fly a longer jet-powered trajectory after the solid rocket boost phase. This could conceivably be useful as the first stage of a small sounding rocket (build up speed, pitch up, release second stage at maybe 15km and 250 m/s) but it’s not likely to lead to an orbital launcher.

It seems more like a subscale demonstrator for an antiship cruise missile than a space launcher, honestly. I note that [LAPAN has previously developed surface to surface missiles and tactical UAVs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Aeronautics_and_Space) for Indonesia’s military.

The point of the rocket booster on a jet powered cruise missile is to avoid the need for a runway — critical for impromptu launches from a mobile unit, but not necessary for a preplanned launch from an airfield. Some cruise missiles use a solid booster to get a ramjet stage up to speed. Those boosters are generally proportionally a lot larger (ramjets need to be moving *fast* to start), and in-line rather than offset, so I think we're looking at a turbojet design.

Comment: Though [I can't imagine](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Map-showing-Chinas-nine-dash-line-and-Indonesias-territorial-waters-around-the-Natuna_fig1_331985306) why Indonesia would an antiship cruise missile, certainly spaceflight must be the only explanation ;-)

Comment: Not to be snarky, but it's basically a Snark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM-62_Snark

Comment: @OrganicMarble Apart from a small matter of scale, yeah.

Comment: The air intake and nozzle could be for flyback

Comment: If they are going to space with a jet then it will evolve to use SABRE.

Comment: @JCRM fly back from 200 meters downrange? ;)